# Is there a term to describe bad memory useage on the stack

Tags: c++, memory

It is known that memory leak is used to describe heap memory not being freed properly throughout a process.

Does it have a term when something similar happen on the stack.

For example, there is a function passing a deep copy object to a function. That function passes another deep copy object of that deep copied object to another function............. which suppose to be done by reference. If the function works for long time, the behavior is very similar to "memory leak".

So, is there a term to describe this kind of "memory leak"?

Sorry, I don't accept Stack Overflow. I think I didn't make my question very clear.

I try to give more example:

```
Object A[100];

if (condition)
{
    Object B[100];
    function (B);
}
else
    function(A);
```

Leaving aside how non-sense the code is, obviously, if `function(B)` is invoked A become useless and there is memory wastage. If `function` run till the end of the program, you have "memory wastage" throughout the program. You cannot tell the guy: "Hey, your program is stack overflowed".

This question came from my another question about Qt.
Qt has a signal/slot mechanism. There is a queued Signal type which makes deep copy of an parameter. However, I found problem to release the memory held by the queued signal. If I tell people "There is a memory leak in the signal", they check the heap. I don't have a proper term to describe my problem.

Comment: I would call that just "allocating stuff too early".

Comment: @zenith yeah.  I don't know of any special term for it, (other than 'bad design':).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be joking? The term you're looking for is none other than  **stackoverflow**!!!

Comment: To my understanding, stack overflow is describing stack resources used up and crash. This is a result when "this process" continue. If the program consumed unnecessary resources like  500mb throughout the program. There won't be stack overflow.

Comment: A stack overflow results in a quick crash. A memory leak is not usually associated with crashes.